# Why I got this error java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable

Tags: android

I am getting error on this code

```
listObjects = (Listitem) extras.getParcelable(OBJECT_LIST);
```

this is how I pass intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mcontext,SingleObjectActivity.class);

intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("Object_list", personArrayList);

intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
mcontext.startActivity(intent);
```

this is second activity

```
public class SingleObjectActivity extends Activity
{
    public static final String OBJECT_LIST = "Object_list";
    private ArrayList<Listitem> Objects;
    public ImageView imgview;
    private Listitem listObjects;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.singleobject);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        imgview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.funnyimage);

        if (extras.containsKey(OBJECT_LIST)) {
            this.listObjects = (Listitem) extras.getParcelable(OBJECT_LIST);
        } else {
            this.listObjects = null;
        }


        if (this.listObjects != null) {
            Picasso.
                    with(getApplicationContext()).
                    load(this.listObjects.getUrl())
                            //load()
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.logo)
                    .fit()
                    .noFade()
                    .into(imgview);

        }
    }
}
```

This is listitem

```
public class Listitem implements Parcelable {
    private int order;
    private String id;
    private String url;
    private String userName;
    private int likes;
    //String name;

   public Listitem(Parcel in){
        this.id = in.readString();
        this.url = in.readString();
       //   this.name = in.readString();

    }


    public Listitem(int order, String id, String url, String userName, int likes) {
        this.id = id;
        this.url = url;
       this.userName = userName;
       this.order = order;
       this.likes = likes;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public int getLikes() {
        return likes;
    }

    public void setLikes(int likes) {
        this.likes = likes;
    }
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(this.id);
        // dest.writeString(this.name);
        dest.writeString(this.url);

    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Listitem> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Listitem>() {
        public Listitem createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Listitem(in);
        }

        public Listitem[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Listitem[size];
        }
    };

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public int getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    public void setOrder(int order) {
        this.order = order;
    }
```

Comment: you are sending list but getting just 1 object

Comment: Why did you comment out the correct code for this case?

Comment: @MuratK. I want to get the result of listitem to put it in picasso. I want to have listobjects.geturl()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You passed full array list but getting just one object

for example try like this:

for sending

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Intent i = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);

ArrayList<MyParcelable> testing = new ArrayList<MyParcelable>();

i.putParcelableArrayListExtra("extraextra", testing);
startActivity(i);
}
```

for receive

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayList<MyParcelable> testing = this.getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("extraextra");
}
}
```

// simple class that just has one member property as an example

```
 public class MyParcelable implements Parcelable {
private int mData;

/* everything below here is for implementing Parcelable */

// 99.9% of the time you can just ignore this
@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

// write your object's data to the passed-in Parcel
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
    out.writeInt(mData);
}

// this is used to regenerate your object. All Parcelables must have a CREATOR that implements these two methods
public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable>() {
    public MyParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new MyParcelable(in);
    }

    public MyParcelable[] newArray(int size) {
        return new MyParcelable[size];
    }
};

// example constructor that takes a Parcel and gives you an object populated with it's values
private MyParcelable(Parcel in) {
    mData = in.readInt();
}
```

}

Comment: okay.. then if want to get the value from the listitem.geturl() how to do that?

Comment: as in example you have "testing" arraylist and which item's you need please get by using testing.get(0).geturl()

Comment: yes put direcly in picsso, if you want to populate in list and then pass in adapter and in adapter you get item and pass. but if you want for specific position you need to give that position

Comment: If you need just single item then why you are passing full array list, just pass single object

Comment: please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents

Comment: as i said in below I am passing in an intent a list contain several info personArrayList.add(new Listitem(item.getOrder(), item.getId(), item.getUrl(), item.getUserName(), item.getLikes())); i want in another activity to use id, url and likes , for now i am using url in the picasso .. did you understand what i am doing ?

Comment: in an example I saw something like this , the first for the arraylist and the second for listitem , that what made me confused 

     if (extras != null) {
            Objects = extras.getParcelableArrayList(OBJECT_LIST);
        } else {
            Objects = new ArrayList<Listitem>();
        }

        if (extras.containsKey(OBJECT_LIST)) {
            this.Listitem = extras.getParcelable(OBJECT_LIST);
        } else {
            this.Listitem = null;
        }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123248/discussion-between-rohit-and-moudiz).

Comment: can you check the question i asekd now , similary to this question

Answer (score 2):

You are putting an ArrayList

```
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("Object_list", personArrayList);
```

But you're trying to fetch just a single Parcelable:

```
this.listObjects = (Listitem) extras.getParcelable(OBJECT_LIST);
```

Those are different types. If you are going to save an array list then you need to call `getParcelableArrayListExtra`

Comment: you mean like this             listObjects = (Listitem) extras.getParcelableArrayListExtra(OBJECT_LIST);
 ? I get error

Comment: Ofc you have get an error. You're casting the list to `ListItem`. You should cast it to ArrayList<ListItem> because that's a list. Not a ListItem

Comment: I am being confused between the listitem and arraylist .. okay then I got the arraylist , how then I get lisitem ?

Comment: What are you trying to transfer? A list of ListItems? Or a single ListItem? The diferente between those is simple. One is a list (with more than one item) and the other is just one item. You are transferring a list but trying to get a single item. Tell me what you want to transfer

Comment: I am passing in an intent  a list contain several info                 `personArrayList.add(new Listitem(item.getOrder(), item.getId(), item.getUrl(), item.getUserName(), item.getLikes()));`
i want in another activity to use id, url and likes , for now i am using url in the picasso .. did you understand what i am doing ?

Comment: Yes. You are passing a list with only one item. Not sure why. I don't think you understand the concept behind lists. Anyway, if you are passing only one item just keep your code on your secondActivity but change your code on your other activity. Instead of calling `personArrayList.add(new Listitem(item.getOrder(), item.getId(), item.getUrl(), item.getUserName(), item.getLikes()));` just use `intent.putParcelableExtra("Object_list", new Listitem(item.getOrder(), item.getId(), item.getUrl(), item.getUserName(), item.getLikes()));`

Comment: okay i am trying your code , i had error cannot resolve method putparcelableextra

Comment: Just use putExtra.

Comment: thanks for your support pedro , rohit helped me in the conversation room