# Error when try to pass list object by using Parcelable

Tags: android, bundle, parcelable

I want to pass a `list object` by using `Parcelable` and `Intent` but I met a problem:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable
```

My Contact.java:

```
public class Contact implements Parcelable {
    private String id;
    private String Name;
    private String Fname;
    private String Phone;
    private String Email;


    public Contact(String id, String Name, String Fname, String Phone, String Email) {
        this.id = id;
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Fname = Fname;
        this.Email = Email;
        this.Phone = Phone;
    }

    public Contact(Parcel in) {
        this.id = in.readString();
        this.Name = in.readString();
        this.Fname = in.readString();
        this.Email = in.readString();
        this.Phone = in.readString();
    }

    //Getter
    public String getId() { return id; }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public String getFname() {
        return Fname;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return Email;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return Phone;
    }

    //Setter

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public void setFname(String fname) {
        Fname = fname;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        Email = email;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone){ Phone = phone; }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(id);
        dest.writeString(Name);
        dest.writeString(Fname);
        dest.writeString(Phone);
        dest.writeString(Email);

    }
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Contact> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Contact>() {
        public Contact createFromParcel(Parcel in)
        {
            return new Contact(in);
        }
        public Contact[] newArray(int size)
        {
            return new Contact[size];
        }
    };
}
```

And My `Intent`:

```
List<Contact> mData = new ArrayList<Contact>();
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, NewContactActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelable("CONTACT_ARRAY_LIST", mData);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

How can I resolve this ? **Thanks you so much**

Answer (score 3):

```
Use putParcelableArrayList instead of putParcelable.
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("CONTACT_ARRAY_LIST", mData); // Be sure "mData" is not null here
```

Comment: `java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable` continue error

Comment: I'm sure it's not null

Comment: @JasonMomoa It's strange for me as its working in my code could you please change List -> ArrayList. Hope it helps

Comment: @JasonMomoa For more info you can refer this link as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39469056/why-i-got-this-error-java-util-arraylist-cannot-be-cast-to-android-os-parcelable

Comment: I don't know Why it's not working T_T, so tired with this, I changed all to ArrayList but it's also not working

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayList` is not parcelable as error clearly says. But it is serializable [as documented](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList), so just go that way instead:

```
bundle.putSerializable("CONTACT_ARRAY_LIST", mData);
```

Alternatively you can use `putParcelableArrayList()`:

```
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("CONTACT_ARRAY_LIST", mData);
```

Comment: I'm using Parcelable, now with your answer I have to change to implements Serializable. Can not other solution with Parcelable ?

Comment: You can use `putParcelableArrayList()` instead. I edited my answer.